# Paypal IPN is coming back as invalid and don't know why

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here is my set up, I will try to keep the code short. This is an ASP.NET MVC4 application

I am setting the information here:

```
    @Html.Hidden("cmd", Model.PayPal.Cmd)
@Html.Hidden("business", Model.PayPal.Business)
@Html.Hidden("return", Model.PayPal.Return)
@Html.Hidden("cancel_return", Model.PayPal.CancelUrl)
@Html.Hidden("notify_url", Model.PayPal.NotifyUrl)
@Html.Hidden("currency_code", Model.PayPal.CurrencyCode)
@Html.Hidden("item_name", Model.PayPal.PlanName)
@Html.Hidden("item_number", Model.Id)

@Html.Hidden("src", Model.PayPal.AutoRecurring)
@Html.Hidden("a3", Model.PayPal.Price)
@Html.Hidden("p3", Model.PayPal.Interval)
@Html.Hidden("t3", Model.PayPal.IntervalType)
@Html.Hidden("txn_type", "subscr_signup")
<input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
```

I set the variables in the controller:

```
PayPal paypal = new PayPal();
        bool useSanbox = true;

        if (useSanbox)// for test
            paypal.ActionUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        else//real
            paypal.ActionUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

        paypal.Cmd = "_xclick-subscriptions";
        paypal.Business = "david_1355300634_biz@domain.com";
        paypal.CancelUrl = "http://localhost:25914/home/";
        paypal.Return = "http://localhost:25914/home/ipn";
        paypal.NotifyUrl ="http://localhost:25914/home/ipn";
        paypal.AutoRecurring = "1";
        paypal.Price = ctx.SubscriptionPlans.First(x => x.Name == signInModel.SubscritionPlan).Price.ToString();
        paypal.Interval = "1";
        paypal.IntervalType = "M";
        paypal.CurrencyCode = "USD";
        paypal.PlanName = signInModel.SubscritionPlan;
        paypal.Amount = ctx.SubscriptionPlans.First(x => x.Name == signInModel.SubscritionPlan).Price.ToString();
```

Then I have this IPN Controller action:

```
//Answer from PayPal
    public ActionResult IPN()
    {
        var signInModel = Session["SignUp"] as SignUp;
        //Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        //string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(this.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            //any param from form
            var text = Request.Form["custom"];
            ctx.SignIns.Add(signInModel);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            //check the payment_status is Completed
            //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            //process payment
            return View("RegistrationConfirmation", signInModel);
        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
            return View("SignUp", signInModel);
        }
        else
        {
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        }
        //change view
        return View("SignUp", signInModel);
    }
```

The thing that is throwing me off is I get routed to the paypal sandbox fine, I log in with a test user, confirm the payment amount, and then click return to the site. Returning hits my IPN action, but I get the response that it is "INVALID". Am I missing a variable here or something? I am relatively new to the api.

Comment: Returning shouldn't be hitting the IPN action. Only the notifyUrl should access the IPN.

Comment: What should the return command go to? A view where I have my logic to save to the db? Does it only hit the return URL if the IPN came back successful?

Comment: The return url is hit before payment is confirmed so there's nothing to verify - it'll always be invalid. You can return to a "thanks for your subscription" page, but wait for the notification before saving anything.

Comment: Oh ok thank makes more sense. So you say wait for notification before saving? How exactly can I subscribe to that notification in my web application?

Comment: PayPal should send a separate request to the notifyUrl with the subscription signup and payment details. So it needs to be externally visible, and not localhost. I would add more logging to the controller so you can see what's received.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. So for the return url I can send them to a thanks for signing up page, and do what I want to do there as far as db interactions. End then for the notify_url it is supposed to hit the ipn, where I can do what I need to do if it ends up being a good or bad payment. That the right flow?

Comment: Awesome if this works, you are my new God. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another one, cmd=_notify-validate should be the first param value that needs to be sent.

As per the official docs

"Verify that your response contains exactly the same IPN variables and values in the same
order, preceded with cmd=_notify-validate."

Comment: so I am passing in the cmd _xclick-subscriptions, do I pass in both, and if so do I put in the the same string? like _xclick-subscriptions&_notify-validate?

Comment: Your returnURL and notifyURL are the same. So when the user they login to paypal, they return back to the same URL as IPN (ActionResult) and you are trying to post back that response which is incorrect. Please always note that IPN is like a webhook and it will be sent later where as return URL is immediate and it's provided for you to checkout cart etc., in your app. Indeally have 2 separate endpoints for returnURL and notifyURL and the response you get at the endpoint for returnURL need not be posted back to PayPal, that's only needed for IPN(which can be notifyURL endpoint).

Answer (score 3):

you're trying to test this locally, well, paypal doesnt' know about localhost. you have to upload the code and test it using the live url